# Contains Or Index of in <s:property> tag Struts2?

Tags: jsp, if-statement, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I have been looking for use `<s:property>` in struts2 if condtion...and I found the solution but `Contains` or `IndexOf` doesn't works in my case can someone help me on syntax....

```xml
<s:iterator value="DirList" status="DirSTS" var="Dir">
    <s:if test="#DetailsStatus.index==#DirSTS.index">
        <s:if test="%{#Dir.indexOf(':'}!= -1">
            <a href='<s:property/>'><small>Click Here </small></a>
        </s:if>                     
    </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

Here **DetailsStatus** is main list status variable...here I want to check if `<s:property>` have `:` symbol

Comment: The error must be in `#DetailsStatus.index==#DirSTS.index` Just print something in and out the first `s:if`, print the value of `Dir` and print the `indexOf` result

Comment: @AndreaLigios weird Dir is printing  DetailsStatusList iterator(Parent) values which is of ArrayList<String> instead of printing DirList :( Since the value itself wrong its failing...

Comment: Please edit your question adding the external iterator and the java sources with their getters, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing that your syntax missing ) closing bracket. Second make sure you have correct values in list which have : Symbol(You have already commented that it have wrong values) 

**here is your code**

```
<s:iterator value="DirList" status="DirSTS" var="Dir">
<s:if test="#DetailsStatus.index==#DirSTS.index">
    <s:if test="%{#Dir.indexOf(':'}!= -1">
        <a href='<s:property/>'><small>Click Here </small></a>
    </s:if>                     
</s:if>
```

**change your code to like this**....

```
<s:iterator value="DirList" status="DirSTS" var="Dir">
<s:if test="#DetailsStatus.index==#DirSTS.index">
    <s:if test="#Dir.indexOf(':')!= -1">
        <a href='<s:property/>'><small>Click Here </small></a>
    </s:if>                     
</s:if>
```